# Craft Commerce 3 - two units same shipping cost

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, shipping

I have products which can be put into the same unit when shipping.

- Eg. If you buy two postcards, shipping costs are still 1x because you
  can put a lot of postcards in one letter.
- or you can get two posters which will be sent in the same tube. so shipping cost don't increase.

How would I set that up in a Shipping Method?
The way I set it up here will double shipping for two units. which is wrong.

[image]